# Deleting a Post/Entry by User in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

I am designing a simple book application. I have the user login, sell or buy books and they have a few account settings too, including **Manage Posts** where the user can delete the book they added into the system.

I am needing help on how to do this. When the user presses the Manage Posts button, I would like an input field that the user can type the Book_ID in and a "Delete" button where they can click it to delete the book out of the system.

Now, I wasn't able to set it up to where when you add a book, it links it to that specific user that logs in (no idea how to do that), so the user will be able to delete any book. I ran out of time on this project so I won't worry about that now. I just need the user to be able to see all the books in the database by the fields on a table: Book_ID, ISBN, Title, Author - and then the user inputs the Book_ID into the input field, clicks "Delete" button and the book is deleted from the database by the user.

database name: nextbook
table: books
fields: book_ID, ISBN, Author, Title (want these viewed)

The following is a template of code I have from another page that I think would be similar. Except, I need the Delete SQL put somewhere :

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM books";

    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM books";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Admin", "Password", "nextbook");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!--Html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" >

    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 30%;
        }

        th, td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

        th {
            background-color: #007d5f;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="NextBook1.css"/>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="Manage_Posts">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>NextBook</h1>
        <a href="Login.php" data-icon="power" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="a" data-mini="true">Sign Out</a>
    </div>


    <br>

    <div class="logo" align="center">
        <img src="Images/image1%20-%20Copy.PNG" width="100" height="100" ">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" align="center">



        <!--<form action="View_Search_Results_Table.php" method="post" align="center"> -->
            <input type="text" name="deletepost" placeholder="Enter ISBN you want to delete">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Post"><br><br>

            <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                <table border="1px solid black;" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book ID</th>
                        <th>ISBN</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Author</th>

                    </tr>
            </div>


            <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Book_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ISBN'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Author'];?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>


        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="nav" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home_Page.php" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#anylink" data-icon="alert"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#anylink" data-icon="mail"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="Manage_User_Accounts.php" data-icon="gear"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter the book ID to delete" name="getdeleteid">

<button type="submit" value="Delete book">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

$getdelete = $_POST['getdeleteid'];

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=nextbook ','user','password');
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_ID = ".$getdelete."");
    $statement->execute(array(1)); 


?>
```

Comment: It says "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ITSS4312\mwa4\Manage_Posts.php on line 93"   

Line 93 is now the first line in this:

 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Book_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ISBN'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Author'];?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>

Comment: I'm not sure, the delete code is fine, your error seems to be, that you don't get any result, it's hard to see the error, because i can't see your whole code

Comment: I'm trying to have a table that shows the table so the user can see which book to delete. Do I put the "$query = "SELECT * FROM  'books'";" statement above the Delete SQL statement, or inside an if, or after?

Comment: Well.. the delete action should be executed on an other php page or with ajax.. but you should not run it in the same file. Otherwise i'm not sure if the POST is working

Answer (score 0):

You should be breaking your script down into multiple parts to make the view easier to work with. Also you should have all the classes in their own pages and use an autoloader (`spl_autoload_register()` or similar) to autoload classes. I have put everything on to one page which looks more complex than it really is. Finally it is helpful to use action words in forms to tell your program you aret trying to do something:

```
<?php
/*
**  @description    It's helpful to have a class that just does some general "stuff"
**                  that all classes could potentially use
*/
class App
    {
        protected   static $singleton;

        public  function __construct()
            {
                if(!(self::$singleton instanceof \App))
                    self::$singleton    =   $this;

                return self::$singleton;
            }

        # Retrieve the $_POST array or a key from it
        public  function getPost($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_POST[$key]))? $_POST[$key] : false;

                return $_POST;
            }
    }
/*
**  @description    It's helpful to have a database class for consistent database retrieval and querying
*/
class Database extends \App
    {
        protected   static  $con;
        protected   $query;
        # Create and retrieve database connection
        public  function getConnection()
            {
                # Create connection if not already set
                if(!(self::$con instanceof \PDO))
                    self::$con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
                # Return the connection
                return self::$con;
            }
        # Query database
        public  function query($sql,$bind=false)
            {
                # Bind parameters for public requests
                if(!empty($bind)) {
                    foreach($bind as $key=>$value) {
                        $bKey           =   ":{$key}";
                        $bArray[$bKey]  =   $value;
                    }
                }
                # Prepare sql
                if(!empty($bArray)) {
                    $this->query    =   $this->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
                    $this->query->execute($bArray);
                }
                else
                    # Do a straight query
                    $this->query    =   $this->getConnection()->query($sql);
                # Send back the object for chaining
                return $this;
            }
        # Use with the query to retrieve database results
        public  function getResults()
            {
                while($row = $this->query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $new[]  =   $row;
                }

                return (!empty($new))? $new : false;
            }
    }

/*
**  @description    Because you are wanting to get database info, may as well extend the Database class
**                  and use it's querying features
*/
class Books extends Database
    {
        # Retrieve one or more books
        public  function getBook($id = false,$type='Book_id')
            {
                $id     =   trim($id);
                $sql    =   "SELECT * FROM `books`";
                if(!empty($id)) {
                    $sql        .=  " WHERE `{$type}` = :0";
                    $results    =   $this->getConnection()->query($sql,array($id))->getResults();
                    return (is_array($results) && count($results) == 1)? $results[0] : $results;
                }

                return $this->getConnection()->query($sql)->getResults();
            }
        # Delete book
        public  function deleteBook($id,$type='ISBN')
            {
                $this->getConnection()->query("DELETE FROM books WHERE `{$type}` = :0",array($id));
            }
    }

class View extends Database
    {
        public static function createSrc($path,$type='js')
            {
                if($type == 'js')
                    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$path.'"></script>';
                elseif($type == 'css')
                    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$path.'" />';
            }
    }


# Should put these defines into a config.php file that you load at the top of every page
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','nextbook');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
session_start();

# Create instance of Books
$App    =   new Books();
# Creaet the book list (could be based on the search)
$search =   $App->getBook($App->getPost('search'));
# Check if the user is trying to delete a book
if($App->getPost('action') == 'delete_isbn') {
    $App->deleteBook($App->getPost('deletepost'));
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<?php echo View::createSrc('http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js') ?>
<?php echo View::createSrc('http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version2.1(beta4)/IE9.js') ?>
<?php echo View::createSrc('http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css','css') ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<?php echo View::createSrc('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') ?>
<?php echo View::createSrc('http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js') ?>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #007d5f;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="NextBook1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="Manage_Posts">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>NextBook</h1>
        <a href="Login.php" data-icon="power" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="a" data-mini="true">Sign Out</a>
    </div><br>
    <div class="logo" align="center">
        <img src="Images/image1%20-%20Copy.PNG" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" align="center">
        <form action="" method="post" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_isbn" />
            <input type="text" name="deletepost" placeholder="Enter ISBN you want to delete">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Post">
        </form>
        <br /><br />
        <table border="1px solid black;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>Book ID</th>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php foreach($search as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Book_id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ISBN'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Author'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="nav" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Home_Page.php" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#anylink" data-icon="alert"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#anylink" data-icon="mail"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="Manage_User_Accounts.php" data-icon="gear"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```